# add class to nth-child with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to add a class using jquery to the nth-child so that it'll work in IE. It doesn't seem to be working, I have followed a few examples with no results. I have linked the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aosto/XghbU/

```
<div id='tasklist'>
    <ul class='header'>
        <li>
            <div class='listitem head'>Number</div>
            <div class='listitem head'>Description</div>
            <div class='listitem head'>Start Date</div>
            <div class='listitem head'>Due Date</div>
            <div class='listitem head'>Edit/View</div>
            <div class='listitem head'>Complete</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div

 #tasklist ul {
clear:both;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
 #tasklist ul li {
clear:both;
margin:3px;
padding:3px;
}
 .listitem {
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}
 .listitem2 {
width:400px;
}

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#tasklist ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass("listitem2");
    });


 <head>
    <link href='css/style.php' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie_style.css" />
<![endif]-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.listitem:nth-child(2)').addClass("listitem2");
    });
</script>
 </head>
```

Comment: You did not include jQuery library in your Fiddle. Do you have the same problem in your own code? Moreover, you don't even have the second `li` tag. How do you know, that it does not work?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing on?

Comment: Works fine when I add more `<li>` and include jQuery -- http://jsfiddle.net/XghbU/1/

Comment: I'm using IE9. Here is my complete <head> code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your selector should be the following in order to address your second div inside the list tag!!

```
$('#tasklist ul li div:nth-child(2)')
```

Or any case you should have at list two list elements in your markup if you are actually trying to target a list element.

Comment: I have tried that. When I inspect it in Chrome, it's working and it adds the listitem2 class just fine. It will not do it in IE9 however.

Comment: appears I had to add <!DOCTYPE html> to my index.php. This seems to have fixed it.

Comment: It should! Try it again. The nth-child selector is not supported by IE8 but it should be by IE9. Besides that, your selector is trying to target an inexistent list tag. Good luck with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(".menu-item").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').toggleClass("display_both");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.